# Skrollr doesn't hide toolbars in iOS or android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, skrollr

I'm using skrollr to achieve several goals in a website (parallax-like backgrounds, changing element opacity etc.) and it's working just fine on both desktop and mobile.

The only problem I noticed is that the mobile OS browsers are not hiding the toolbars anymore. Once I disable the skrollr it's all fine - the toolbars are gone immediately after I start scrolling the page. When the skrollr is in use the toolbars stay visible all the time.

Is there a way to use skrollr and still keep the regular browser behavior?

Let me know if any additional info would help you understand the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for us to hide/show the address bar programmatically. It's not even possible to just hide it (iOS 7 made this completely impossible, whereas 7.1 will add some meta tag to hide it completely), let alone show it again.

https://gist.github.com/scottjehl/1183357

> The old hack of using window.scrollTo to hide the URL bar doesn’t work anymore; therefore there is no way to hide the URL bar or toolbar without user’s intervention scrolling the page.
>
> If you are not using a natural scroll, you will have problems (detailed below).

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

> A property, minimal-ui, has been added for the viewport meta tag key that allows minimizing the top and bottom bars on the iPhone as the page loads. While on a page using minimal-ui, tapping the top bar brings the bars back. Tapping back in the content dismisses them again.
>
> For example, use <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, minimal-ui">.

https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2194915

Comment: Thank you, tried the minimal-ui already - not exactly what I need. I also noticed that the skrollr demo page has the same problem.

Comment: Have been trying for ages to find a workaround for that. The problem is that because skrollr is scrolling inside the div, and the divs overflow is set to hidden, iOS never realizes that the content is actually higher than the viewport and therefore never grows the screen to hide the bars...